# Apache httpd.conf issue with Rewrite

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I am trying to add the following lines to my Apache httpd.conf file (I have version 2.2 on Windows 7)

```
Alias /my_ember_proj "C:\my_ember_code\dist"
<Directory "C:\my_ember_code\dist">
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
AllowOverride None
Require all granted
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /my_ember_proj/index.html#$1 [L]
</Directory>
```

However the following lines are failing

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /my_ember_proj/index.html#$1 [L]
```

I know this because the server starts without these 4 lines (I don't know where I can find any specific failure details. I do not see any specific error in the logs folder).

Comment: AFAIK, Apache 2.2 does not accept `Require all granted`

Comment: Any follow-ups on the question?

Comment: How did you get on with the below answer, testndtv?

Answer (score 1):

As already mentioned in comment, the `Require` directive, provided by `mod_authz_host` is not available in Apache 2.2. The [module was introduced](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_authz_host.html) in Apache 2.3 and later version.

So, first check if the Apache server is indeed 2.2.

Next, confirm whether [the rewrite module](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_rewrite.html) has been loaded or not. In the same `httpd.conf` file, search for the following:

```
LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so
```

If there is a `#` preceeding it, remove the `#` symbol, save file and restart the server.